# Logstash index pattern not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have trouble configuring logstash.
Everytime I try to start logstash I receive this

```
message=>"SIGTERM received. Shutting down the pipeline.", :level=>:warn
```

This is my config

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/logs/Xorg.0.log"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

Logstash-forwarder

```
{
    "network": {

        "servers": ["localhost:5043"],
 "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt",
    "timeout": 15

    },

    "files": [{
        "paths": [

            "/var/log/syslog",
            "/var/log/auth.log",
            "/var/log/*.log"
        ],

        "fields": {
            "type": "syslog"
        }
    }, {
        "paths": ["-"],
        "fields": {
            "type": "stdin"
        }
    }, {
        "paths": [
            "/var/log/apache/httpd-*.log"
        ],
        "fields": {
            "type": "apache"
        }
    }]
}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Try starting it with debugging enabled.

Comment: @AlainCollins
Thanks for your help, I updated to logstash 2.x
but now having other problems :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381656/vagrant-elk-stack-error-connection-refused

but thanks for the hint here